# Wordpress PHP Variable in SQL query no results

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am having a problem, i want to get the term_id from my _terms table where the name equals the string in the Variable $sitio.

```
function getTerms($sitio, $prefix){
  echo '$sitio=';
  var_dump($sitio);
  global $wpdb;
  //$tagLocsIds = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT term_id FROM {$prefix}terms WHERE name = '{$sitio}'");
  $tagLocsIds = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT term_id FROM {$prefix}terms WHERE name = '%sd'", $sitio));
  echo "Id=";
  var_dump($tagLocsIds);
  return $tagLocsIds;
}
```

I tried different queries to get the Ids but output is always array(0) { } even though the $sitio is not empty:

$sitio=string(47) "84503 Altötting" Id=array(0) { } $sitio=string(44) "01067 Dresden" Id=array(0) { } $sitio=string(55) "88239 Wangen im Allgäu" Id=array(0) { }

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Is there a reason you’re not using the standard WP functions to do this? It’s not desirable to query the WP database directly - apart from it being possible the the way WP uses the db could change, it’s also it’s much more complicated to get the query right than to use the functions the WP provides specifically to make it easier to do this

Comment: @FluffyKitten What WP function could i use for this?

Comment: How about get_terms? The clue is in the name :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Thank you so much it works now. Just doing that:   $term = get_term_by('name', $sitio, 'mec_location');
  $tagLocsIds = $term->term_id;